# batch file create txt file with multiple lines in specific folder

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch files and so far, I have figured out how to make a txt file with multiple lines

```
(
echo one
echo two
echo three
```

)>hello.txt

I found a way to do this, but it pastes the file in the same location and simply copies the txt file into another folder, but I want to put this txt file directly into that folder. Could you show me how to modify this code so that I can put this in a specific folder. Or give me an example of how you would do it this way, or another way? Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Echo Off
Set "out=C:\users\YourUserName\Desktop"
(
  Echo;Line 1
  Echo;Line 2
  Echo;Line 3
) > "%out%\YourFileName.txt"
```

---

or:

```
@Echo Off
Set "out=C:\users\YourUserName\Desktop"
 >  "%out%\YourFileName.txt" Echo;Line 1
 >> "%out%\YourFileName.txt" Echo;Line 2
 >> "%out%\YourFileName.txt" Echo;Line 3
```

---

Where:

- **Set out** : sets path to write file.
- **%Out%**: specify the path with a variable.
- **\YourFileName.txt**: *self-explanatory*.
- **>** : Redirects **stdout** (*standar output*) to file. (**>>** indicates write, but not erase old data from file *-concatenates it-*).

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out again! But here's the issue. One of the folders in the path has a space, and won't work with that.

Comment: @JohnSmith Did you test it. As the quotes around the filename should ensure that it works, even with spaces

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to thank you again @Honguito98 for helping me out. And yes jeb, spaces don't matter, I'm still a newbie so minor errors such as syntax were in the way, and after a little tweaking finally fixed. Thanks guys!